# Width of the tables inside an inline-block element

Tags: html, css

I have two inline-block elements(width: 50%) inside a div(width:100%).
inside the first inline-block element i have table with many columns. This table is not rendered in its given 50% width. (It comes under the second inline-block element.)

```
<style>
#col1 {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    width:50%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#col2 {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: green;
    width:50%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
</style>



<div>
<div id="col1"><table><tr><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td></tr><tr><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td><td>hai</td></tr></table></div><div id="col2">content</div></div>
```

Refer this example in: http://jsfiddle.net/6L3h8h7k/

In the above example,the first row of the table its overlapped by the second inline-block element.

How to make this table to occupy only the 50% width.

Some one kindly help me sort out this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you want the table to behave? Do you want the table columns to wrap so they all fit? Do you want the "extra" columns hidden? What does your desired result look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this style to your table

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Comment: All that will do, in this instance, is collapse the width of the individual cells to try to fit into the desired space, causing the content of the cells to overlap each other.

Comment: Yes if you want table to be fit inside the box that cell will overlap, cell can not wrap like text.

Comment: This is what in question asked "How to make this table to occupy only the 50% width."

Comment: I think it goes without saying that the content should still be legible.

Comment: And i think content is dummy in fiddle ?

Answer (score 1):

JSFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6L3h8h7k/2/)

Change your css to this one

```
#co {
     display: inline-block;
}
#col1 {
    background-color: red;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}

#col2 {
    float:right;
    background-color: green;
    width:50%;
}

tr td { display:inline-block;}
```

Add "co" id to your first div

```
<div id="co">
```